# How to get background to have all 4 margins

Tags: css, background-image

If I want to have my background be separated into 4 equal-sized divs, that isn't hard for me to accomplish. What's puzzling, though, is that only the top and left margins appear, and I cannot get the right specification to have margins on the right and bottom appear.

```
.bg {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

With the code above, you can see that there is a top and left margin only.

Comment: For each div, play with [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) to display the background image properly.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: The added code snippet doesn't have any background image. What do you mean?

Comment: @HashemQolami if you use that CSS and then use:

<body>

<div class="bg"></div>

</body>

the margin only appears on the top and left of the window. Even if you specify margin-right, border-right, or padding-right, the same whitespace doesn't appear.

Comment: @czmudzin Ah I think I've misunderstood your question. That happens because of specifying `width` and `height` of `100%` to the fixed positioned element while the body has a default margin of `8px` for all its sides. Two choice: either [remove the body's margin](http://jsbin.com/cepecu/1/edit) or expand the diemensions of the fixed div by offest properties like so: http://jsbin.com/cepecu/2/edit - Besides, you might want to consider a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) in order to override the default stylesheet applied to elements by the UA.

Comment: But if you're willing to have the margin around the body, you probably need to use CSS3 `calc()` expression to specify the fixed elements' dimensions. [Something like](http://jsbin.com/cepecu/3/edit): `calc(100% - 16px);`

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured out is to just set the `height` and the `width` to slightly under 100%. Thanks for the other feedback.